# Is WhenActivated supposed to be called on deactivation?

Tags: reactiveui

I have implemented `ISupportsActivation` and added calls to `this.WhenActivated` for both the view model and the view. It seems to me that the delegate gets called twice. Both for activation and deactivation. Is this by design or am I doing something wrong? If this is by design, is there any way to know if the call is for activation or deactivation?

The view model is data bound to a `ViewModelHost` if that matters in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know one case this happens, that is if you use `RoutedViewHost` or `ViewModelViewHost`. As reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30946278/reactiveui-view-locator-performance) and [there](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/930), when switching the view content, the old/previous view model gets deactivated-reactivated-(animated)-deactivated.

And you get called on `WhenActivated` at that time.

That is clearly a bug and it's caused by the implementation of `TransitioningContentControl`.